# .htaccess rewrite mod for remove pages extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is my `index.php`:

```
<?PHP
//
$urls="404";
//
   IF (ISSET( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ))
   {
    $urls=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
   }
//
$db_hand = MySQL_CONNECT( '127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '2000' ) OR DIE( "Error Connecting DataBase" );
$db_hand = MySQL_SELECT_DB( 'content', $db_hand ) OR DIE( "Error Select DataBase" );
$sele = "SELECT * FROM `dg_content` WHERE urls='".$urls."' LIMIT 1";
$sele = MySQL_QUERY( $sele ) OR DIE( "Could not execute query.." );
$cols = MySQL_NUM_ROWS( $sele );
$rows = 0;
IF ($cols<=0)
{
    $sele = "SELECT * FROM `dg_content` WHERE urls='404' LIMIT 1";
    $sele = MySQL_QUERY( $sele ) OR DIE( "Could not execute query.." );
    $cols = MySQL_NUM_ROWS( $sele );
    $rows = 0;
}
//
// ---- and etc and etc
//
}
```

And this is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?urls=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But whene I type `http://example.org/surakarta` on browser, the results seems to be 404.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You should avoid `mysql_*` functions as that api is depreciated. Also you're script is wide open to [**`sql injection`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [`PDO`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`MySQLi`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: `^/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$` should begin with `([0-9]+)` or `/?([0-9]+)`

Comment: @Darren Actually, the use of `mysqli_` and/or PDO are not safeguards against SQL injection; not on their own that is. Using [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or **PDO** with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) will.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right, I'm being too general :-( my day's already shithouse!

Comment: @Darren I know the feeling. That's why I keep an *already-made* text file lol Having to retype this multiple times takes its toll ;-) cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- Contemplated doing the same thing recently as a matter of fact! But I don't think SO loves me enough for that haha!

Comment: @Darren Why wouldn't it? I just use the standard tags for links along with some bold formatting, then bingo! You did that in your first comment. Just copy what I put up for the links to, then double-bingo ;-)